# Wordpress Gutenberg Block - ReactJS - get Third Party Data from Firebase.Firestore

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, firebase, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying write a Gutenberg Block to load some Data from Googles Firestore.

This is my first ReactJS project cause I thought this should be easy :D
Backend is just fine and set up with all needed properties.
I think I'm only missing one little thing here, but that has been bothering me for days.

the point where I'm stuck is in `const getData = () => {...` at `getDoc(...)`. It seems that the `Promise<DocSnap>` never get's resolved

```js
    import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
    import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

    const { render } = wp.element;

    let state = '';
    let data = '';

    if ( typeof window.firebaseOptions !== 'undefined' ) {
        // Initialize FirebaseApp
        const firebaseApp = initializeApp( window.firebaseOptions );
        state = 'initialized';
        const db = getFirestore();
        const docRef = doc( db, 'myDoc', window.docId );

        const appendData = ( result ) => {
            const text = document.createTextNode(
                window.docId+ ': ' + result
            );
            data = text;
            state = 'texted';
        };

        const getData = () => {
            state = 'loading';
            getDoc( docRef ).then( ( data ) => {
                state = 'promised';
                let result = '';
                if ( doc.exists ) {
                    result = JSON.stringify( doc.data(), undefined, 2 );
                } else {
                    result =
                    'No Doc with ID ' + window.docId + ' found.';
                }
                appendData( result );
            } );
        };
        getData();
    } else {
        //TODO Warning message
    }

    const Block = ( { element } ) => (
        <div >
            <div element={ element } >Doc: { window.docId }</div>
            <div element={ element } >state: { state }</div>
            <pre>{ data }</pre>
        </div>
    );

    window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const blocks = document.querySelectorAll( '.wp-block-my-wp-block' );
        blocks.forEach( ( block ) => {
            render(
                <Block element={ block } />,
                block
            );
        } );
    } );
```

And here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Hi Michael, do you have a test page somewhere? I can help to look into it.

Comment: Hi Dale, thanks for your comment. No i have no test page, was so frustrated to put this on ice. Maybe i will just put n iframe on wordpress to show the data from a react page.

Comment: That's also a solution. I wonder is it necessary to use React just to display some data? It can be done via plain JS.

Comment: The plugin should display live race results from esport league, so data changes twice per second so i thought react could show those data "live" without refreshing the page all the time. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's the `onSnapshot()` implementation in Firestore. It doesn't matter it's JS or React. 

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen